# Vertically Centering one side of a Multiline equation

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a long PDE which I wish to write in the form F(phi)=0; however, it is too long to be written on a single line. As of now I have it written in my LaTex document simply using:

```
\begin{align*}
\phi_t + e^{-x}\phi_x - e^{-x}\phi + \Lambda e^{-x} \phi_z - 9 \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi^2\phi_z^2 + 6 \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi \phi_z^2 - 3 \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi^3 \phi_{zz} + 3 \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi^2 \phi_{zz} \\
 - \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi_z^2 - \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi \phi_{zz} + \mathcal{E} \epsilon^2 \phi_z \phi_{zzz} + \mathcal{E} \epsilon^2 \phi \phi_{zzzz} = 0
\end{align*}
```

which works fine enough showing:

[image]

However, ideally I would like for it to print something closer to
[image]

where the "=0" is centered between the two lines on the left hand side. Is this possible in LaTex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aligned` for such formulars:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{aligned}
\phi_t + e^{-x}\phi_x - e^{-x}\phi + \Lambda e^{-x} \phi_z - 9 \mathcal{M}
    \mathcal{E} \phi^2\phi_z^2 + 6 \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi \phi_z^2 - 3
    \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi^3 \phi_{zz} + 3 \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E}
    \phi^2 \phi_{zz} \\
 - \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{M} \mathcal{E} \phi_z^2 - \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{M}
    \mathcal{E} \phi \phi_{zz} + \mathcal{E} \epsilon^2 \phi_z \phi_{zzz} +
    \mathcal{E} \epsilon^2 \phi \phi_{zzzz}
  \end{aligned}
  \enskip = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

See, e.g., [section 3.7 of the `amsmath` user's guide](https://texdoc.org/serve/amsmath/0#section.3.7) for more information about building blocks.